# A-Frame - Path for Importing Images Issue - Change from Web Origin to Local Project

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, aframe, glteximage2d

I have a working A-Frame site deployed here: https://clevrar.co.za/robben-island-demo

This was created with the IdeaSpace CMS.

I have downloaded the site in order to try and add a service-worker script to it (I'm fine with that part and don't need assistance there), and it works surprisingly well and as expected, except the PhotoSpheres used in the scenes aren't displaying as the source is pointing to an online domain. See deployment attempt here: https://boundless-hole.surge.sh/ and the errors here:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rje0G.jpg)

The path to the images in my local project currently is: public/assets/user/photospheres/

How do I reference them correctly in the index.html folder so that they will be visible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the files locally on Your server (and as far as i see they are [there](https://boundless-hole.surge.sh/public/assets/user/photospheres/mpJHGDflVfrP9o3f1dLKMGNQpVL4uxw4Wbdl07qR85PixFFq7T1czz0TIevi.jpg) ),

why not change the `<img>` `src` attribute in the `<a-assets>`
to `https://boundless-hole.surge.sh/public/assets/user/photospheres/image_name.jpg` instead of `https://clevrar.co.za/public/assets/user/photospheres/image_name.jpg` ?

Comment: Thanks @Piotr.

I changed the values in a JSON file that I hadn't done before from, for example:

"#uri":{"#value":"https:\/\/clevrar.co.za\/public\/assets\/user\/photospheres\/pMUwljMGt2Ckv7cckruR81DRKSZuZ1fDv7b2YzE5IFwKXjqHLz3c8ZwGAdp8.jpg"}},

to

"#uri":{"#value":"https:\/\/boundless-hole.surge.sh\/public\/assets\/user\/photospheres\/pMUwljMGt2Ckv7cckruR81DRKSZuZ1fDv7b2YzE5IFwKXjqHLz3c8ZwGAdp8.jpg"}},

This made the first photosphere display correctly, but every time I navigate to a subsequent sphere, I get:

core:propertyTypes:warn "img-photosphere-XX" asset not found.

Comment: The only reference to the image files anywhere in the HTML is this:

<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="public/assets/user/photospheres/mpJHGDflVfrP9o3f1dLKMGNQpVL4uxw4Wbdl07qR85PixFFq7T1czz0TIevi.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="public/assets/user/photospheres/mpJHGDflVfrP9o3f1dLKMGNQpVL4uxw4Wbdl07qR85PixFFq7T1czz0TIevi.jpg" />

Here's the HTML & JSON:

https://jsfiddle.net/L50j51qL/1/